# Listing disconnected users using Powershell

Tags: powershell, credentials

Our network setup has multiple zones. I have a local domain user, a user to RDP to a jump server on another domain and a user to RDP to a third domain that cannot be connected to from the first. I need to obtain a list of disconnected RDP and Citrix sessions on a server in the third domain.

Running *quser \server:csn012* on my local computer gives:
  `quser.exe : No User exists for \server:csn012`
On the jump server the same command gives:
  `quser : No User exists for *`
On the server itself *quser* gives:
  `USERNAME            SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 user9                                   2  Disc      2+16:09  23/05/2017 10:31`

My Powershell script initially sets *$Credential* using *PromptForCredential*. I have not got very far with *RunAs* and *Invoke-Command*. How can get the results as if run on the remote server without changing any network configuration.

Comment: have you tried `invoke-command -computername someserver -credential (get-credential) -scriptblock {}`?

Comment: I thought I had but no one had provided the format quite as succinctly. Thank you. This unfortunately returns:  
  `Connecting to remote server csn012 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the 
request.`

Comment: Elsewhere in my script _gwmi Win32_Process_ works quite well.

Comment: https://www.gitbook.com/book/devopscollective/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/details

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 but I am not in a position to effect any change to the environment. I have to work around the limitations set by our internal IT department.